# Is there a way to move objects, such as labels, over other objects, like pictureboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently, I'm working on a project to track coordinates on a form using 2 labels, One tracks the X coordinates and another tracks the Y coordinates. So far it only works fine without a PictureBox. However, adding a PictureBox into the equation creates some problems. Most are negligible, but one confused me. When moving my mouse over the PictureBox both the labels and PictureBox stop moving altogether. Its only start moving when I move my cursor outside the PictureBox's area. Is there a possible way to fix this?

Code:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        x = e.X; y = e.Y;
        label1.Location = new Point(x - label1.Width, y);
        label2.Location = new Point(x, y - label2.Height);
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
        label1.Text = x.ToString(); label2.Text = y.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: @Amy Are you sure this is winforms? I don't remember there is an `OnMouseMove` method.

Comment: @Sweeper It *could* be WPF, but I don't think so.  There is a `OnMouseMove` in Winforms:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmousemove(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The control you hover over now gets the MouseMove event.  You need to set the form's Capture property to true to ensure that it get all the events.

Comment: As @HansPassant says, you need to manage "Capture".  Grab the capture on MouseDown, move things around on MouseMove, and release the capture on MouseUp.  There are lots of examples of doing something like this floating around the web.  Any reason why you are overriding OnMouseMove rather than using the MouseMove event?